# webapi-use claims with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, claims-based-identity

The method has been secured with roles=admin:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/values        
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }}
```

I am successfully to use claims with Webapi project where `Individual User Account` is selected where the claim `admin` is injected in

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Now I want to test with `Windows authentication` option where a IAuthenticationFilter is implemented:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var windowsPrincipal = context.Principal as WindowsPrincipal;
        if (windowsPrincipal != null)
        {
            var name = windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
            // TODO: fetch claims from db (i guess based on name)
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(windowsPrincipal.Identity);

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            // here is the punchline - we're replacing original windows principal 
            // with our own claims principal


            context.Principal = claimsPrincipal;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

and added to class `webapiconfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthenticationFilter());

        ...
    }
}
```

The claim `admin` is in `User.Identity.Claims` when debugging webapi project, however it could not be authorized in method /api/values/get.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default identity `RoleClaimType` is `identity/claims/groupsid` which is not `role`.

[image]

By setting `RoleClaimType` to `identity/claims/role` in the `ClaimsIdentity` constructor, we can get it passing `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`

```
public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var windowsPrincipal = context.Principal as WindowsPrincipal;
        if (windowsPrincipal != null)
        {
            var name = windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name;

            // TODO: fetch claims from db (i guess based on name)                
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(windowsPrincipal.Identity,
                null,
                "Negotiate",
                "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");
            //identity

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            // here is the punchline - we're replacing original windows principal 
            // with our own claims principal


            context.Principal = claimsPrincipal;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Here is the new identity:

[image]